# How should I identify myself in a copyright notice / license?

Tags: licensing, copyright, license-notice

<sub>(migrated from [programmers.SX](http://programmers.stackexchange.com))</sub>

I'm placing a copyright notice with some (FOSS) license in a `LICENSE` file in a software package I'm publishing; or it's a license block in a source file.

It starts like [this](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause):

> Copyright `<YEAR>` `<COPYRIGHT HOLDER>`
>
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted etc. etc. etc.

Ok, so, the year is the year I'm creating the license file / block. That one's easy. But - how should I identify myself, the copyright holder? Obviously, I'm going to write my name, but:

- Do I specify an affiliation, even if I, rather than the organization, am the holder? e.g. a research institute I work at?
- Do I specify an address, or a town/city name?
- Do I write an email address?

  - If so, what if that address is tied to an organization/company, which I've not listed and is not the copyright holder?
  - And what if I *only* have those problematic kinds of email addresses?
- If the answer to both previous questions is "no", what's to distinguish me, John Smith, from all the other John Smith's out there?

Comment: The gpl has a discussion of that here https://www.gnu.org/prep/maintain/html_node/Copyright-Notices.html  And they somewhere have a lengthier discussion (that I read at some time, but am not immediately finding again) suggesting that you provide an email address and web url (among other info) in your copyright notice.

Answer (score 2):

Copyright notices are mostly pointless. What they do is

- remind people that the software is actually copyright-protected
- make it easier to reconstruct the copyright history of a file
- can make it easier to prove copyright infringement (in particular, falsifying or removing notices may be criminal)
- but mostly they are just a remnant of 80s-era copyright law in the USA where such notices were still mandatory.

The syntax for copyright notices is mainly given by US copyright law, which roughly <del>suggests</del> requires:

```
(Copyright | ©) <year>(,<year>)* <author-name>
```

- The year should be the year where you *publish* the file, not create it.
- The name may be your natural name, or you may use a pseudonym.
- You do not have to provide any contact details, but you may do so (preferably outside of the copyright notice itself).
- The copyright notice must of course list the copyright holder.
- If some institution is not a copyright holder, it makes no sense to mention the institution in a copyright notice. Of course you may mention affiliation in related documentation, e.g. as part of a file header or in a readme file.
- In an academic context, there might be a requirement to acknowledge a funding source in all publications. I would recommend keeping these only in the documentation, or to use a license like Apache 2 or the GPLv3 family that can require the preservation of such attribution notices.

Contact details can be helpful

- to identify you more clearly, or
- for users to ask you for support.

The former suggests that long-lived contact details would be more helpful, the latter suggests that providing contact information might not be desirable at all. See also [“I have a Toyota Corola”](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/11/14/i-have-toyota-corola/) – the story of how the cURL author receives emails from car owners because they found an address in the car's license information. Instead, let your documentation point to a public bug tracker, forum, or mailing list (whatever medium you are comfortable with).